# Would a project with Angular-Java-MySQL be called a 4-tier application-architecture?

Tags: angular, architecture

Or if it were 3 tier, would Angular be considered as a client layer or 
presentation layer?
I'd like to understand more of these off-base (That's what I believe until I get enlightened) terminology of '**n-tier**'.
Any info would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

- Angular -> Presentation Tier
- Java    -> Middle Tier
- MySQL   -> Data Tier

Yor application is based on a n-tier architecture. You can find a good explanation in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384398.aspx)